# Play a sport or do a sport

Tags: word-choice, british-english

Do  BrE speakers use "play sports" =a few or "play a sport" or "play sport" when refer to one  particular  sport or different particular  sports. But when talking about sporting activities in general they use "do sport" or "do sports"=a few?

I came across an example  in my book with "play a sport". The author is British.

Comment: You _play_ a sport involving games (football, tennis, golf...), but you _do_ or _take part in_ swimming, athletics etc.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, So the following "rule" is correct, isn't it?   BrE speakers use "play sports" =a few,  or "play a sport", or "play sport" when refer to one particular sport or different particular sports. But when talking about sporting activities in general they use "do sport" or "do sports"=a few.

Comment: I didn't say that! _He plays football, she takes part in athletics, they take part in sports._ Google Ngrams gives no British English entries for _he plays sport_ or _they do sports_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, that's why I was surprised to see it in my book. So only *do*  *sport* =one and in general, and *do sports* if a few work in BrE. Right?

Comment: Read my previous comment again!

Comment: @Kate Bunting, I mean a general statement: I do sport. I do different sports. I don't do any sport. But I play tennis, football, etc.  Play is used with the name  as in play football, tennis, etc.  Is this right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133848/discussion-between-kate-bunting-and-antonia-a).